# *.herokuapp.com wildcard certificate expiry

Tags: ssl, heroku, tls1.2

I have node app running on a free dyno on Heroku, so it is accessed by https://.herokuapp.com

I'm just experimenting so I'm happy to leave it under the herokuapp domain, but I noticed the *.herokuapp.com wildcard certificate is expiring on 22nd June 2020, and there is no automatic certificate management for free dynos.

Is heroku going to renew their wildcard certificate so I can continue to use my free dyno, or will it stop working on 22nd unless I pay for a hobby dyno at $7 a month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard certificate is managed by Heroku for all tenants on the herokuapp.com domain. The whole point of this certificate is that you don't need to manage a separate certificate for your app.

As such, Heroku will renew the certificate on their own before its expiration. You don't have to do anything about it. Your app will continue working after June 22.